# Backbone view not refresh event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I have one view (`HomeView`) render template using text! plugin. 
This is Home view :

```
var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize: function() {
        myCart.updateQtyLabel("qtyCart");
   },
   el: '#webbodycontainer',
   events : {
       "click #addToCart" :  function(){
           myCart.addToCart(newItem);
           myCart.updateQtyLabel("qtyCart");
           $("#containernewpromotion").html(promotionItem);
       }
   },
   render : function(){
       this.$el.html(homePanel);
       $("#containernewpromotion").html(promotionItem);
   }
});
```

This is html template :

```
<% var items = deserializeJSONToObj(localStorage.getItem("Cart"));%>
  <%  if(items != null){  %>
    <% var i = 0; %>
       <% _.each(items, function(item) { %>
          <% if (i < 4){ i++; } else { return false; }%>
          <div class="promotionColumn">
             <div class="itemImg">
                  <a href="#itemDetail"><img src="<%=WebConfig.PartImageBrand + item.PictureName%>" width="135px"/></a>
             </div>
          </div>
  <% }); %>
<% } %>
```

This is `itemDetail` view :

```
 var ItemDetailView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        alert("test");
    },
    render: function(){
        alert("test2");
    }
});
```

When I click on `<a href="#itemDetail">`, I got a warning message in chrome console `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.`, and  `alert` in `ItemDetailView` is not working.

The url goes `/#itemDetail` but the template used in `HomeView` still displayed in `itemDetail` router. `HomeView` content is dropped from `itemDetail` page when I press `refresh` in my browser.

Any idea what could be causing this please. Thanks.

Comment: can you setup a demo on jsFiddle?

Comment: @user10: Here dear `http://jsfiddle.net/vPnjd/1/`

Comment: @Domo your demo is not complete

Answer (score 0):

The events object in a backbone view is of the following structure

```
"events" : {
    "event selector" : "handler"
},
"handler" : function(){

}
```

The value in the events object is a string, not a function.